# Binding the Text Property of a custom TextBlock which uses "new" Text Property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textblock, wpf-animation

I have a custom `TextBlock` which overrides the base `Text` Property with `new`:

```
public new string Text
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            if (value.Equals(base.Text)) return;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                // Hide text
                SlideOut();
                FadeOut((_, _) =>
                    base.Text = value);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text))
            {
                // Hide, then show text
                SlideOut();
                FadeOut((_, _) =>
                {
                    base.Text = value;
                    SlideIn();
                    FadeIn();
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // Show text
                base.Text = value;
                SlideIn();
                FadeIn();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am a big fan of Binding, so I am trying to use it as such:

```
<customElements:AnimatedTextBlock
        x:Name="WarningTextBlock"
        Text="{Binding Warning}"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Margin="4,8"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

`OnPropertyChanged();` updates the Property of the `TextBlock`, but skips over my `new` `Text` Property. If I change back to a `TextBlock`, everything works fine.

I can manually apply `WarningTextBlock.Text = "WARNING TEXT";` and it works, but I'd like to understand whether it's possible to target my `new` Property instead of the base `TextBlock.Text` with Binding.

Comment: *which overrides the base with `new`* - technically that's hiding, not overriding. Soo.. why do you need to `new` it? Why not make another property (that relays Text if you need) and bind that?

Comment: `Text="{Binding Warning}"` would only work when Text is a dependency property. Your new Text property is an ordinary CLR property. Consider deriving from TextBlock without declaring a new property, but just register another PropertyChangedCallback for the TextBlock's Text property.

Comment: Both of these sound like great suggestions. I don't know how to implement either. Can you each provide an example as an answer? I tried to bind my own Property, but it was not a Dependency Property and the compiler gave an error.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using VisualStateManager or Triggers to do all this in just XAML?

Comment: This is probably a good idea. I am, at this point, too deep into code-behind. I have a whole class of animations that I can call upon.

I may move over to XAML and Triggers in the future.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I am also not using XAML because it is almost impossible to exclusively catch a value change and fade out before changing the text. You would still need code-behind to fade out first, then change the value, and fade in.

Comment: Looks to me like you haven't heard about Enter and Exit Actions for triggers. But that's by the by. Best of luck

Comment: I know about said actions. Is there a way to start an ```EnterAction``` before changing the ```Text``` Binding? I can't be showing the ```Text``` to the user before fading out.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research with knowledge that I should look into `DependencyProperty`, I figured out how to implement it.

Here is the most helpful bit of code:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextContent", // Name of your actual Property
        typeof(string), // The type of your Property
        typeof(AnimatedTextBlock), // The type of the parent element
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnTextChanged)); // The method which is called after the base Property changes

    public string TextContent
    {
        // These are the first to get called
        get => (string) GetValue(TextContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextContentProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBlock) d;
        var newText = (string) e.NewValue;

        // Do things with your element
        // Such as: tb.Text = newText;
        // In my case, do animations            
    }
```